# Retrieving CRL binary cert using LDAP3 Python Module

Tags: python-3.x, pki, ldap3

I am trying to retrieve a CRL cert hosted on an LDAP server using Python 3.9.16 and LDAP3 module

When I use ldapsearch and the command

`/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://<HOST>:<PORT> -Z -b "c=us" -s sub "(ou=rootCA)" certificateRevocationList`

I get the CRL in ASCII format, ready to use.

When I use python and ldap3 with the code

```
#!/bin/python3
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ANONYMOUS, SAFE_SYNC, ALL
server = Server('ldaps://<HOST>', port = 636, use_ssl = True, get_info=All)
base_dn = "c=us"

conn = Connection(server, client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC, auto_bind=True, auto_encode=False)
entries = conn.search(search_base=base_dn, search_filter='(ou=rootCA)', attributes='certificateRevocationList')

print(tuple(entries))
```

The crl data is displayed in an encoded form not sure what type, lots of '\x'.

How do I get the CRL in straight ASCII format as the CRL is written within LDAP?

I have been through the ldap3 documentation on
https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searches.html#search-scope-and-aliases